# Is the below nested radical converge?

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, square-numbers

Sorry i can't write the below nested radical  using latex , I accrossed it in some web , i w'd like if it is a convergent or no ? and thanks

[image]

Comment: Nested radical is probably a more proper term for it. Anyway, taking logarithm makes the problem much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expression can be written as
$$ 2^{1/2!} 3^{1/3!} 4^{1/4!} \ldots = \prod_{n=2}^\infty n^{1/n!}  = \prod_{n=2}^\infty \exp\left(\frac{\log n}{n!}\right) = \exp\left(\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\log n}{n!}\right)$$
The sum is easily seen to converge, and therefore the product converges as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: And it converges quite fast ! The pitty is that inverse symbolic calculators do not find anything for the result.